# Mounting /dev/ and /sys/ filesystems

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, sysfs

I have a question regarding /dev/ and /sys/ pseudo file systems creation in kernel. While kernel booting, rootfs mounts at the end and init process will be started after that. At kernel boot time, device drivers create device nodes(under /dev/) and sysfs entries(under /sys/) during device and driver binding. This device and driver binding can happen before rootfs mounts. How the /dev/ and /sys/ filesystems will be created under root(/) before rootfs mounts.

Comment: The **/dev** and **/sys** pseudo filesystems are primarily for userspace.  The kernel always boots with an initramfs before there is ever a root filesystem on a block device.   Note device drivers do not *"create device nodes"*; they merely have major & minor numbers.

Comment: AFAIK when you use systemd in your initramfs aswell as in the real system, it has a special option to rescue over your /dev and remount it in the final rootfs. That is not needed for sys though, since sys is an in-kernel FS that can always be mounted whereever needed.

Comment: I think, we can build kernel image without initramfs. Because I could see the options in usr/Kconfig can be enabled or disabled, which means we can disable initramfs for a kernel build(Ex: CONFIG_INITRAMFS_SOURCE default value is ""). I have checked character device source, it seems the details are stores in cdev_map and kobj_map. can you guide to understand how and who mounts /dev/ during the 2 scenarios(when initramfs enables and disables).

Comment: *"I think, we can build kernel image without initramfs"* -- No, you are conflating the initial rootfs with the option of providing a cpio archive file to populate that initramfs. Study **Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt**

Answer (score 0):

During the early stages of the Linux boot process, before the root filesystem (rootfs) is mounted, several filesystems can be mounted. The exact number and types of filesystems mounted may vary depending on the distribution, configuration, and specific boot process of the Linux system. However, there are typically three key filesystems mounted in the early boot stages:

**1. Initramfs (Initial RAM Filesystem):** The initramfs is an initial filesystem that is loaded into memory during the early stages of the Linux boot process. It contains essential utilities, device drivers, and configuration files necessary for booting the system. While technically not mounted like other filesystems, it serves as a temporary working filesystem during the initial boot process. The initramfs is responsible for setting up device nodes in /dev/, mounting the /sys/ filesystem, and performing other tasks needed to initialize the system before transitioning to the root filesystem.

**2. /dev/ (Device Filesystem):** The /dev/ directory is a special filesystem that contains device nodes representing various hardware devices. These device nodes are used for device file operations, such as reading and writing to hardware devices. During the early boot stages, the /dev/ directory is typically created and populated with device nodes for detected hardware devices. This is often managed by the udev or mdev utility within the initramfs.

**3. /sys/ (Sysfs Filesystem):** The /sys/ filesystem is an in-memory filesystem (tmpfs) mounted by the Linux kernel early in the boot process. It provides a structured way to interact with and configure kernel features and exposes information about kernel objects, devices, and parameters. Sysfs is essential for kernel configuration and hardware management.

These filesystems are mounted to set up critical components, initialize devices, and provide the necessary infrastructure for the kernel and early boot processes to function correctly before transitioning to the root filesystem. The specific sequence and handling of these filesystems may vary between different Linux distributions and boot configurations.